# Show decimal numbers with condition

Tags: angular, angular11

I have a variable with a number, sometimes it's an integer sometimes a decimal. I want to show it with 2 digits after the point once it's a decimal, and without any decimal, if it's an integer.
I mean, if it's 4, I'd like to show it as 4, but if it's 4.3, I'd like to show it as 4.30.
How can I do it in Angular11?
I tried `| number:'1.0-2'`  which shows it as an integer or decimal with one digit (e.g 4.3)

Comment: What about `1.234` or `1.235`?  How would these numbers be displayed?

Comment: I don't care about this case actually. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried ` | number:'1.2-2' ` ? (not tested). Take a look here: https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe#digitsinfo

Comment: @shayd solutions works, you can also write simple statement 

    num.toFixed(2)

Comment: These solution are god for the case of 4.30, but not for just 4 (It makes it 4.00)

Answer (score 0):

With Angular [DecimalPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe) you can only configure it to fit one of your two cases, but you could make your own decimal pipe.

Just create a new pipe, extend the Angular DecimalPipe,
checks first if the number is integer return it as it is, else just return the transform value of the Angular DecimalPipe.

```
import { DecimalPipe } from '@angular/common';
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'customNumber',
})
export class MyDecimalPipe extends DecimalPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    if (Number.isInteger(+value)) return value;

    return super.transform(value, args);
  }
}
```

In your template as [@ShayD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5107490/shayd) recommended in his comment, min fragment must be 2 and the max also.

```
<div> Integer {{ 4 | customNumber: '1.2-2' }} </div>
<div> Decimal {{ 4.3 | customNumber: '1.2-2' }} </div>
```

Here is my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-idn7ks?file=src/app/app.component.html) solution